# Evaluation of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the series
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, (n^2 - n +1)^2}{(n-2)! + (n+2)!}.$$
The series converges to some value near $0.12122103\cdots$. The series may also be seen in the form
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, (n^2 - n + 1)^{2}}{(n-2)! \, (n^2 + n -1)^{2}},$$
which leads to a ratio of primes and composites. Reasonably there should be a way to find an exact value, rather than a decimal only value. What are some hints, methods, or the like that could lead to an exact value?

Comment: What kind of sorcery led you to this

Comment: After looking at the result, I really enjoy the *reasonably* ! Cheers. :-)

Comment: Trying to rework, I think that we could end with "only" six hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Leucippus, why did you reject my edit? https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3396183/revisions

Answer (score 3):

I did a little tampering, and it's lead to something which may help:
$$S=\sum_{k\geq2}\frac{(-1)^k(k^2-k+1)^2}{(k-2)!(k^2+k-1)^2}$$
Making the substitution $k=n+2$ gives
$$S=\sum_{n+2\geq2}\frac{(-1)^{n+2}((n+2)^2-(n+2)+1)^2}{(n+2-2)!((n+2)^2+n+2-1)^2}$$
Which simplifies to 
$$S=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\biggr(\frac{n^2+3n+3}{n^2+5n+5}\biggl)^2$$
Then, let $c_n=\frac{x^n}{n!}\biggr(\frac{n^2+3n+3}{n^2+5n+5}\biggl)^2$, and $$s(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}c_n$$
Thus, $$S=s(1)$$

And if you are an algebra wizard, you can turn $$\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}$$
Into something in the form $$\frac{(n+a_1)(n+a_2)\cdots(n+a_p)}{(n+b_1)(n+b_2)\cdots(n+b_q)}\frac{x}{n+1}$$
Then $$s(x)=\;_pF_q(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_p;b_1,b_2,\dots,b_q;x)$$
Which you can ask Jack D'Aurizio about.

---

EDIT:

We may observe that 
$$\frac{n^2+3n+3}{n^2+5n+5}=\frac{\left(n+\frac{3+i\sqrt3}{2}\right)\left(n+\frac{3-i\sqrt3}{2}\right)}{\left(n+\frac{5+\sqrt5}{2}\right)\left(n+\frac{5-\sqrt5}{2}\right)}.$$
Set $$t_n=\frac{(n+p_1)^2(n+p_2)^2}{(n+q_1)^2(n+q_2)^2}\frac{x^n}{n!},$$
so that
$$\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n}=\frac{(n+1+p_1)^2(n+1+p_2)^2(n+q_1)^2(n+q_2)^2}{(n+1+q_1)^2(n+1+q_2)^2(n+p_1)^2(n+p_2)^2}\frac{x}{n+1},$$
and $$t_0=\left(\frac{p_1p_2}{q_1q_2}\right)^2.$$
Thus
$$\sum_{n\ge0}\left(\frac{(n+p_1)(n+p_2)}{(n+q_1)(n+q_2)}\right)^2\frac{x^n}{n!}=\left(\frac{p_1p_2}{q_1q_2}\right)^2\,_8F_8\left[{{1+p_1,1+p_1,1+p_2,1+p_2,q_1,q_1,q_2,q_2}\atop{1+q_1,1+q_1,1+q_2,1+q_2,p_1,p_1,p_2,p_2}};x\right].$$
Your sum is given by the cases 
$$p_1=\frac{3+i\sqrt3}{2}$$
$$p_2=\frac{3-i\sqrt3}{2}$$
$$q_1=\frac{5+\sqrt5}{2}$$
$$q_2=\frac{5-\sqrt5}{2}$$
and $x=-1$.

Answer (score 2):

There is an exact expression for this summation.

I hope and wish that you enjoy hypergeometric functions since,given by a CAS, the result (not reported here since it would cover a full page of text) involves a few $\Gamma$'s plus $\color{red}{28}$ different hypergeometric functions of the type $_k F_k(.)$  for $k=2,3,4,5,6$.

Numerically, the result is $0.12122103756674277429282539384136467560849890271145$